# Python: Find and return a specific dictionary in a complex nested dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a nested dictionary, which is really complex. I am trying to find a specific key/value combination and return that value ("value" is a dictionary). I try to use a recursive function but get None returned.

As you might see, I'm learning to code, and this might be a naive approach. Explanations of what I am doing wrong and examples of better ways to do this is appreciated.

An example of the dictionary is like this (the real one is much more complex but follow similar patterns:

```
inDict = {
    "key1": "val",
    "key2": [],
    "key3": {"asf": {"val1": 0, "key6": {}}, "key7": False},
    "key4": {"test2": {"my_key": {"my_dict": True}, "id": "temp"}},
    "key5": 5
}
```

my attempt to solve it looks like this:

```
def channel_dict(inDict):
    def recurse_func(d):
        if type(d) == dict and bool(d):
            print(d.keys())
            if 'my_key' in d.keys() and type(d['my_key']) == dict:
                return d['my_key']
            else:
                for v in d.values():
                    if type(v) == dict and bool(v):
                        print(v)
                        return recurse_func(v)

    return recurse_func(inDict)

channelDict = channel_dict(inDict)
```

After the value of "key3" is processed, my code exits the recursive function with None as return value.
As I wrote above, all help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting **None** because your function does a recursive search inside the **first** nested dictionary it finds i.e. `key3` in this case. If the key is not there it doesn't loop through the remaining keys in the actual dictionary.

I have modified your function

```
def channel_dict(inDict):
    def recursive_func(d, k='my_key'):
        if isinstance(d, dict):
            if k in d and isinstance(d[k], dict):
                return d[k]
            for key in d:
                item = recursive_func(d[key], k)
                if item is not None:
                    return item
        elif isinstance(d, list):
            for element in d:
                item = recursive_func(element, k)
                if item is not None:
                    return item

        return None

    return recursive_func(inDict)

channelDict = channel_dict(inDict)
```

Here `k` is the key whose data that you want to get.
The above returns `{'my_dict': True}` as output to **channelDict**

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I did not realize that I only entered the first nested dictionary, your improvement did the trick!